# xrandr detects monitor but no signal is shown

Tags: linux, xorg, manjaro, xrandr

So at the boot of  the system i put the hdmi out at the right of of another screen and it has worked thus far.

Lately xrandr detects the output but the screen gives no signal.

It's not a cable issue (ran trough two cables) and it's not a monitor issue either (tried on a second monitor and i've changed trough multiple modes.

Down here are some info.

Help is appreciated thanks

`uname -a`

`Linux anon-pc 5.4.164-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Dec 8 09:53:07 UTC 2021 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

`xrandr`

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2724 x 768, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1366x768      60.00*+  40.00
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74
   1024x768      60.04    60.00
   960x720       60.00
   928x696       60.05
   896x672       60.01
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82
   960x600       59.93    60.00
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25
   840x525       60.01    59.88
   864x486       59.92    59.57
   700x525       59.98
   800x450       59.95    59.82
   640x512       60.02
   700x450       59.96    59.88
   640x480       60.00    59.94
   720x405       59.51    58.99
   684x384       59.88    59.85
   640x400       59.88    59.98
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32
   512x384       60.00
   512x288       60.00    59.92
   480x270       59.63    59.82
   400x300       60.32    56.34
   432x243       59.92    59.57
   320x240       60.05
   360x202       59.51    59.13
   320x180       59.84    59.32
HDMI-1 connected 1360x768+1364+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 575mm x 323mm
   1360x768      60.02*+
   1920x1080     60.00    50.00    59.94
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00
   800x600       75.00    60.32
   720x576       50.00
   720x576i      50.00
   720x480       60.00    59.94
   720x480i      60.00    59.94
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94
   720x400       70.08
```

`sudo dmesg |grep intel`

```
[    0.640850] intel_idle: MWAIT substates: 0x11142120
[    0.640851] intel_idle: v0.4.1 model 0x8E
[    0.641098] intel_idle: lapic_timer_reliable_states 0xffffffff
[    0.647417] intel_pstate: Intel P-state driver initializing
[    0.647618] intel_pstate: HWP enabled
[    0.647735] intel_pmc_core INT33A1:00:  initialized
[   12.201799] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain package
[   12.201801] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain dram
[   12.279766] acpi INT33D6:00: intel-vbtn: created platform device
[   12.281146] intel-vbtn INT33D6:00: failed to read Intel Virtual Button driver
[   12.672340] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain package
[   12.672342] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain core
[   12.672343] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain uncore
[   12.672344] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain dram
[   12.837263] fb0: switching to inteldrmfb from EFI VGA
[   12.871815] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[   15.223788] audit: type=1130 audit(1640445743.052:16): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
[   18.966483] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-22.50.19.14.f.bseq
```

`sudo dmesg |grep vga`

```
[    0.380830] pci 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: setting as boot VGA device
[    0.380830] pci 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: VGA device added: decodes=io+mem,owns=io+mem,locks=none
[    0.380830] pci 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: bridge control possible
[    0.380830] vgaarb: loaded
[   12.837429] i915 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: deactivate vga console
[   12.839424] i915 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=io+mem:owns=io+mem
```

`lspci`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 5906 (rev 02)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 02)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point LPC Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168NGW [Stone Peak] (rev 10)
```

Comment: try `xset dpms force off; xset dpms force on`

Comment: Nope. The  second screen kind of "blinks"  (the no signal message flashes off but then it goes up again)

Comment: Yes, that's what it's suppose to do.  Sometimes this will wake up an unresponsive screen.   Possibly the monitor has failed, or maybe just the backlight?

Comment: I tried another monitor and another cable... still nothing

Comment: Ok it might be an hw issue... i spammed the command that you have given me and now i see green lines... i think that the hdmi controller might be screwed... rip

Comment: sad.  Test the cable too!

Comment: i'll try thanks

Answer (score 1):

Most likely an hw issue... sorry guys